# Pandas asof_locs Example

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried searching the entire internet for an example of how to use `pandas.index.asof_locs` but couldn't. I don't quite understand what to pass in to the second `mask` variable.

I have a list of datetime variables `dt` and a target dataframe with dates and price data `df`. For every datetime value in `dt`, I would like to find the closes datetime index from `df`. I know if `df.index.asof` and it takes in a single input at a time and i'm trying to avoid loops so wanted to check out `asof_locs` which can take a list i think.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [`Index.asof_locs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.asof_locs.html) documentation, `mask` is a boolean array of the positions of the non-NA values in the index.

Here is an example of use:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-03', 'NaT', '2023-01-07', '2023-01-09'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
idx2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-31', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

idx.asof_locs(idx2, idx.notna())
```

Output: `array([-1,  1,  0])`